# Angular TypeScript class instance

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a typescript class:

```
 export class User {

    id: number;
    userName: string;
    knownAs: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    created: Date;
    lastActive: Date;
    photoUrl: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    surname: string;
    givenname: string;

    get fullName(): string {
        return `${this.givenname} ${this.surname}`;
    }

    sayHello() {
        console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.surname} ${this.givenname}!`);
      }
}
```

I have a Service function:

```
    user: User;
    this.userService.getUser(this.loggedUser.nameid).subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
        this.user.givenname = this.loggedUser.given_name;
        this.user.surname = this.loggedUser.family_name;
        console.log(this.user.fullName);
        this.user.sayHello();
      });
```

the result in the console:
console.log(this.user.fullName) = undefined
this.user.sayHello(); = ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'sayHello'

After when I get back the user data from the server, how I can reach property and function which I've defined in the user class?

Comment: I think the issue is probably in your service class, which we would need the code for. Also, what does the debugger show you’re getting back?

Comment: Is the `user` result on the subscribe function actually an instance of the `User` class?

Comment: As @theMayer said, I think we will need the `getUser()` code to understand the error.

Comment: You're not creating an instance of User here ? You could use `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `prototype` object for `User` like this. `User` you are getting from the service may not be a `prototype` object and hence the functions on it are not available.

```
user: User;
this.userService.getUser(this.loggedUser.nameid).subscribe((user: User) => {
    this.user = Object.assign(new User, user) //-->notice the use of new here..
    this.user.givenname = this.loggedUser.given_name;
    this.user.surname = this.loggedUser.family_name;
    console.log(this.user.fullName);
    this.user.sayHello();
  });
```

Update:
JavaScript classes are not exactly an object oriented model. As per MDN:

> JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Also, as pointed out by @theMayer in comment, the service that returns `user` can also return the proper `User` object which has the prototype functions. So, its the displacement of code to create the object from the client to service. I like that approach, just because that means any other consumer of the service can use the object behaviors (functions), without having to duplicate (`Object.assign`)the object.

So, in the `UserService.ts` (or wherever that `userService` is defined), something like:

```
getUser(id: string):User {
  //existing logig
  return Object.assign(new User(), user)//--> there are other ways to create object too, this is just one way.
}
```

Comment: But this completely defeats the purpose of having a class in the first place, at least so far as TypeScript is concerned.

Comment: @theMayer you are right in a way, if you read at MDN, JavaScript classes are not really classes, its just a syntax improvement over the old Prototype based inheritance. Added the link to answer, explore more. Thx

Comment: Yes, but the whole purpose of Typescript is "compile-time" checking. So if you do this, you're getting all of the drawbacks and none of the benefits.

Comment: The issue you have is not TypeScript related. This is JavaScript classes behavior. Where TypeScript comes to play is, say for example, you are assigning an object that is not `User` to the variable `user`, like `this.user = Object.assign(new OtherObject, user)` then TypeScript will help you at compile time.

Comment: That’s correct, which is why I asked for the service code. Something is broken there (you’re not going to write an angular service in plain JS unless you’re way off the reservation).

Comment: @theMayer you are right, sorry I took you for OP and kept explaining the answer =), yes, the service might as well create the user prototype object and return. That's an other way to do it if the OP has control over that service. I'll add that to the answer to improve. thx.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating an instance of User.
Here is an example of how it could be implemented :

```
 export class User {

    id?: number;
    userName?: string;
    knownAs?: string;
    age?: number;
    gender?: string;
    created?: Date;
    lastActive?: Date;
    photoUrl?: string;
    city?: string;
    country?: string;
    surname?: string;
    givenname?: string;

    constructor(args: User = {}) {
      this.id = args.id;
      this.userName = args.userName;
      this.knownAs = args.knownAs;
      this.age = args.age;
      this.gender = args.gender;
      this.created = args.created;
      this.lastActive = args.lastActive;
      this.photoUrl = args.photoUrl;
      this.city = args.city;
      this.country = args.country;
      this.surname = args.surname;
      this.givenname = args.givenname;
    }

    get fullName(): string {
        return `${this.givenname} ${this.surname}`;
    }

    sayHello() {
        console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.surname} ${this.givenname}!`);
      }
}
```

Use [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) to create your User instance :

```
user: User;
this.userService.getUser(this.loggedUser.nameid)
  .pipe(map((user: User) => new User(user)))
  .subscribe((user: User) => {
    this.user = user;
    this.user.givenname = this.loggedUser.given_name;
    this.user.surname = this.loggedUser.family_name;
    console.log(this.user.fullName);
    this.user.sayHello();
  });
```